# Some of my data logging take really longer than the others

Tags: logging, arduino, adafruit

I need to take an Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger and make it log data of 8 sensors at 100 samples per second. The problem is: some data take longer time to be written in the txt file. The gap between each sample is 10ms (or so) but, suddenly (around 30s, i = 2700, and 37s, i = 3150, after it starts), it takes 30-50ms to get the data, and, then, comes back to 10ms. It isn't good for the application, because we're trying to compare some methods of this kind of data collection, and this problem would get in the way of synchronization. I need to know why this happens, and how to solve it.

```
#include <BlockDriver.h>
#include <FreeStack.h>
#include <MinimumSerial.h>
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SdFatConfig.h>
#include <SysCall.h>

#include <SPI.h>
//#include <SD.h>

SdFat sd;

const int chipSelect = 4;
const int cardDetect = 7;
const int ledPin = 3;
String fileName = "DATA.TXT";
bool alreadyBegan = false;

int sensorPin[] = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,0,A7};
uint8_t sensorVal[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
const int sensorNo = 8;

boolean interrupt = false;
boolean displayed = false;
int i = 0;
unsigned long loopCount = 0;
unsigned long beforeTime = 0;
unsigned long afterTime = 0;
unsigned long t1 = 0;
unsigned long t2 = 0;
unsigned long dif = 0;
int sampleSize = 6000;

File dataFile;

void setup(void)
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(cardDetect, INPUT_PULLUP);
  for (int k = 0; k < sensorNo; k++) {
    pinMode(sensorPin[k], INPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("");Serial.println("INITIALIZING.....");
  iniCard();
  Serial.println("");Serial.println("INITIALIZED!!!");
  Serial.println("");Serial.println("========================");
  Serial.println("");Serial.print("File Name: ");Serial.println(fileName);
  Serial.println("");Serial.println("========================");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop(void)
{
    loopCount++;
    t2 = micros();
    dif = t2-t1;
    if (dif >= 9999){
      if (i==0){
        dataFile = sd.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
        beforeTime = micros();
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      }
      else if (i == sampleSize){
        afterTime = micros();
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      }
      t1 = t2;
      if (i < sampleSize){
        String dataString = "";
        dataString += micros();
        dataString += ",";
        for (int j = 0; j < sensorNo; j++) {
          sensorVal[j] = analogRead(sensorPin[j]);
          dataString += String(sensorVal[j]);
          if (j < sensorNo-1) {
            dataString += ",";
          }
        }
        Serial.println(dataString);
        dataFile.println(dataString);
        i++;
      }
      else{
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        if (!displayed){
          dataFile.close();
          displayed = true;
          Serial.println("");Serial.println("========================");
          Serial.print("Frames: ");Serial.println(i);
          Serial.print("Loops: ");Serial.println(loopCount);
          Serial.print("Start Time: ");Serial.println(beforeTime);
          Serial.print("End Time: ");Serial.println(afterTime);
          float period = (afterTime - beforeTime)/i;
          Serial.print("Period: ");Serial.println(period);
          float freq = 1000000 / period;
          Serial.print("Freq: ");Serial.println(freq);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
    }
}

void erro() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(250);
}

void iniCard() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  while (!digitalRead(cardDetect)) {
    erro();
  }

  // Card seems to exist.  begin() returns failure
  // even if it worked if it's not the first call.
  if (!sd.begin(chipSelect) && !alreadyBegan) { // begin uses half-speed...
    iniCard();  // Possible infinite retry loop is as valid as anything
  }
  else {
    alreadyBegan = true;
  }

  // card initialized:
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

Comment: It could be String operations it could be SD operations. Did you try to time the code to narrow down the slow code?

Comment: Yes, each iteration it saves micros() in the .txt file so I know the difference between each sample